# Are there still Replicators in the Asgard's home galaxy?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

At the end of the *Stargate SG-1* episode [*Reckoning*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reckoning_%28Stargate_SG-1%29) the [Replicators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replicator_%28Stargate%29) invading the Milky Way galaxy are rendered inert by the super-weapon on Dakara. But did this defeat of the Replicators include all of the Replicators in the Asgard galaxy of Ida?

I know that the invasion was technically started by Fifth in [*Gemini*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemini_%28Stargate_SG-1%29#ep165), resulting in the destruction of Fifth along with all of the Replicators that came with him. This allowed Replicator Carter to start anew with her disruptor immune variants, but did Fifth bring all of the Ida Replicators with him, or did some remain behind?

Comment: Per my comment/reply [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/49707/how-do-the-replicators-get-to-the-asgard-galaxy?rq=1#comment93418_49709), why isn't the entire universe filled with Replicators?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the Asgard aliens feared the power of the Replicators and tried to exterminate them but couldn't because of its resistance of energy weapons and rapid "evolution".  Even though the Asgard race were futile at the extermination of the Replicators, they can still detect them.  If any of them were left behind in the galaxy after the Fifth brought the Replicators to the Milky Way, then the Asgard people would know.

Since Fifth controlled all the Replicators, the rest were gone, he brought all of the Replicators with him to the MilkyWay.  After Replicator Carter disposed of him, she assumed control.  With no care for the Asgard's galaxy she only attacks in the Milky Way galaxy.

Basically if there were any Replicators the Asgard wouldn't have done a group suicide.

Comment: The group suicide was in response to the Ori attacking their planet. They did not want their knowledge and technology to be stolen and used against the fifth race.

Comment: I thought the suicide was because their cloned bodies were degrading and they thought just to end it.

Comment: Hmm true, that was in there somewhere. Maybe the immediacy of it was just because of the Ori.